# How do I set a notification function to be triggered whenever one of my QWidget derived objects are created?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have an abstract base class DisplayWidget derived from QWidget. This class is inherited by several other concrete widget classes (for example Tree, Button, Label etc.).

I have a parser function that reads a text file and creates objects of these derived classes. The parser creates appropriate objects based on a 'type' string for each entry in the file.

My requirement is that, for objects of a certain class (for example Tree), I need to perform some actions when they are created. For various reasons, these actions cannot be done in Tree constructor.
My idea is to create a notification call-back function for the base class DisplayWidget, that gets invoked whenever a new object is created by the parser.
Then in the call-back, I can do a dynamic_cast and perform such special actions for objects of interest.

But how do I set this up? If I invoke the notification function from the base class constructor, it will be executed before the derived class constructors have run, which can cause problems. I'm not even sure if dynamic_cast would even work in that case.

Is there a way to trigger a delayed function? Something like deleteLater() that's invoked in the next iteration of the event loop.

Comment: If parser creates the objects, why it cannot call a specific function (depending on the type) on a newly created object too?

Comment: Syam, cannot you just emit a signal and connect to that with the slot of the corresponding operation?

Comment: Well, as per the current design, the parser function invokes a factory method for certain type of objects and for some other types, it calls other create functions. So the actual point of object creation is not in one factory routine. That's because the type of objects are not very similar to be grouped by one factory. That's why I was looking for a solution in the base class so that it will be triggered no matter hot the object is created.

Comment: @syam: sounds like a bit fishy design.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yeah. I don't like it either. I think some refactoring is due.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I changed the parser object to call a registered call-back function whenever a new object was created. It didn't end up hackish since the parser already had separate creation functions for each widget type.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing some kind of callback, I would simply use a factory, e.g. `DisplayWidgetFactory`. The factory would have methods like this:

```
DisplayWidget* DisplayWidgetFactory::createTree( <params> )
{
    DisplayWidget* widget = new Tree( <params> );
    _someMemberObject->handleNewObject( widget );
    return widget;
}
```

Then in your code, instead of doing `new Tree(...)` you do `_factory->createTree(...)`.

It would be best to deliver the factory to the parser via its constructor, so the parser doesn't need any additional information the factory might need.
Your main code could then look something like this:

```
NewObjectHandler* handler = new NewObjectHandler();
DisplayWidgetFactory* factory = new DisplayWidgetFactory( handler );
Parser* parser = new Parser( factory );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to trigger a delayed function?

You could use a QTimer, but that would be hack'ish.

The real solution would be to emit signals when the construction is ready (e.g. from your parser), and the desired slot (callback) would be called.

Please read upon the following topic which is essential in Qt:

[Signals and slots](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/signalsandslots.html)

Depending on how loosened coupling you wish to have, you could also call the desired operation from your "parser" which, by the way, seems to go beyond the parser limits, and seems to behave as a factory, too. I would probably decouple the two since they are two different responsibilities.

It is hard to give concrete code for your question since it is not detailed enough, but you could do something like this:

```
connect(factoryFunctorPointer, SIGNAL(widgetObjectCreated(WidgetType)), SLOT(handleWidgetObjectCreation(WidgetType)));
```

The factoryFunctor class would be something like this:

```
struct FactoryFunctor
{

    public signals:
        void widgetObjectCreated(WidgetType);

    public:
        bool operator()() const
        {
            // Create the widget object
            emit widgetObjectCreated(myWidgetType);
        }
};
```

Then you could also declare your type information like:

```
enum Type {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz,
    Tree,
    ...
};
```

Note that this way, you would not even need the dynamic cast since you would have the type information. For sure, you could still use the cast if needed when the type information is not enough.

The remaining bit is the slot which would be basically like this:

```
YourClass::handleWidgetObjectCreation(WidgetType widgetType)
{
    switch (widgetType) {
        case Foo:
            doFoo();
            break;
        case Bar:
            doBar();
            break;
        case Baz:
            doBaz();
            break;
        case Tree:
            doTree();
            break;

        // etc

        default:
            doDefault();
            break;
    }; 
}
```

Note that, for QObjects, hence QWidgets, you could also skip the type enumeration properly as the [QMetaObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QMetaObject.html) available for QObjects can take care of that. You can query such information like class name, etc. I mostly wrote this for being generic, although the explicit may beyond the scope of what you need with QObjects.

That being said, the rest should be similar for "Qt notifications".

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should add some signal to the parser, something like:

```
void objectCreated(YourBaseClass *createdItem);
```

Then connect to this signal. If you need process this signal in next event loop iteration then connect this signal with last parameter set to `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

```
connect(parser, SIGNAL(objectCreated(YourBaseClass*)),
        receiver, SLOT(onObjectCreated(YourBaseClass*)),
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Another way to run things in next event loop iteration is use meta data and invoke method like that:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(objectPointerForInvkedMethod,  // must be a QObject
                          "methoNameToInvokeInNextIteration",
                          Qt::QueuedConnection,
                          Q_ARG(YourBaseClass*, createdObjectPointer));
```

Comment: Qt::QueuedConnection is purposeless here. Also, I do not see the need for invokeMethod. IMHO, connection is enough for a beginner. :)

Comment: To add to the complication, my parser uses all static functions :-(
So that will have to be changed to emit a signal. Further, as explained in the comment to the question, the object creation points are somewhat scattered.